# TypeORM don't generate migration in project created by TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, typeorm

I'm using a template generator to create a project, but it exits with error when I try to generate the template

#### Expected Behavior

Generate the migration with sql scripts

#### Actual Behavior

```
$ C:\Users\alexa\lab\ProjectTypeOrm\node_modules\.bin\typeorm migration:generate -n User
Error during migration generation:
C:\Users\myname\lab\ProjectTypeOrm\src\entity\User.ts:1
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at C:\Users\alexa\lab\ProjectTypeOrm\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.importClassesFromDirectories (C:\Users\alexa\lab\ProjectTypeOrm\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:10)       
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

```
typeorm init --name ProjectTypeOrm --database mysql --express --docker
cd ProjectTypeOrm
docker-compose up
yarn
yarn typeorm migration:create -n User
yarn typeorm migration:generate -n User
```

#### My Environment

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Operating System | Windows 10 Home |
| Node.js version | 14.17.6 |
| Typescript version | 3.3.3333 |
| TypeORM version | 0.2.38 |
| Yarn | 1.22.11 |

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are running the Typeorm CLI with NodeJS, but your entities are still uncompiled Typescript files. One way to fix this by running the CLI using `ts-node`.

```sh
npx ts-node node_modules\typeorm\cli.js migration:generate -n User
```

If you often use this command, you could add a custom script to your `package.json` so that you wouldn't have to type the whole thing every time.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "orm": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
  "devDependencies" : {
    "ts-node": "^10"
  }
}
```

And then call it in your terminal.

```sh
npm run orm -- migration:generate -n User
```